# Why Element 'iframe' is not supported for youtube links with mews/purifier?

Tags: laravel, htmlpurifier

In laravel 8 app with mews/purifier: 3.4,
I need to show youtube video(defined using <iframe ...)

As youtube iframe block is cleared by \Purifier::clean( method I found branch
[Laravel Package Purifer not work with iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25649525/laravel-package-purifer-not-work-with-iframe)

and tried to modify my config/purifier.php file like:

```
'settings' => [
    'default' => [
        'HTML.Doctype' => 'HTML 4.01 Transitional',
         // I added this iframe rule
        'HTML.Allowed' => 'iframe[src|width|height|class|frameborder],h1,h2,h3,div,blockquote,table,tbody,tr,td,figure,b,strong,i,em,u,a[href|title],ul,ol,li,p[style],br,span[style],img[width|height|alt|src]',
        'CSS.AllowedProperties' => 'font,font-size,font-weight,font-style,font-family,text-decoration,padding-left,color,background-color,text-align',
        'AutoFormat.AutoParagraph' => false,
        'AutoFormat.RemoveEmpty' => true,
    ],
    'test' => [
        'Attr.EnableID' => 'true',
    ],
    'youtube' => [
        "HTML.SafeIframe" => 'true',
        "Filter.YouTube" => 'true',
        // I suppose this rule means all iframes are allowed
        "URI.SafeIframeRegexp" => '%.+%',
    ],
```

But I got error :

```
Element 'iframe' is not supported (for information on implementing this, see the support forums)
(View: /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/HRBrazy/affiliate/resources/views/news/show.blade.php)
```

How that can be fixed ?

Comment: Did you follow the very clear instructions in the error message to "see the support forums?"

Comment: I am not sure what is "support forums"  ? Please give a reference... Where can I search for a decision here?

Comment: My first step would be putting "htmlpurifier support forum" into a search engine. Obviously if they mention it in an error message there must be one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add 'youtube' at last as config, it works for me in laravel 10: 
`clean($request->body, 'youtube');`

Answer (score 1):

The configuration looks right for HTML Purifier. This script does what it should:

```php
// requiring HTMLPurifier.auto.php up here somewhere, no other code up here but that.

$dirtyHtml = '
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ydYDqZQpim8" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen></iframe>
';

$knobs = [
  'AutoFormat.AutoParagraph' => false,
  'AutoFormat.RemoveEmpty' => true,
  'CSS.AllowedProperties' => 'font,font-size,font-weight,font-style,font-family,text-decoration,padding-left,color,background-color,text-align',
  'Filter.YouTube' => 'true',
  'HTML.Allowed' => 'iframe[src|width|height|class|frameborder],h1,h2,h3,div,blockquote,table,tbody,tr,td,figure,b,strong,i,em,u,a[href|title],ul,ol,li,p[style],br,span[style],img[width|height|alt|src]',
  'HTML.Doctype' => 'HTML 4.01 Transitional',
  'HTML.SafeIframe' => 'true',
  'URI.SafeIframeRegexp' => '%.+%',
];

$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
foreach ($knobs as $setting => $value) {
  $config->set($setting, $value);
}
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);

$cleanHtml = $purifier->purify($dirtyHtml);

echo $cleanHtml . PHP_EOL;
```

This gives me:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ydYDqZQpim8" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

If I comment out the lines that are in your `'youtube'` configuration block, however, like so:

```php
// ...
$knobs = [
  'AutoFormat.AutoParagraph' => false,
  'AutoFormat.RemoveEmpty' => true,
  'CSS.AllowedProperties' => 'font,font-size,font-weight,font-style,font-family,text-decoration,padding-left,color,background-color,text-align',
  // 'Filter.YouTube' => 'true',
  'HTML.Allowed' => 'iframe[src|width|height|class|frameborder],h1,h2,h3,div,blockquote,table,tbody,tr,td,figure,b,strong,i,em,u,a[href|title],ul,ol,li,p[style],br,span[style],img[width|height|alt|src]',
  'HTML.Doctype' => 'HTML 4.01 Transitional',
  // 'HTML.SafeIframe' => 'true',
  // 'URI.SafeIframeRegexp' => '%.+%',
];
// ...
```

...then I get your error:

```
PHP Warning:  Element 'iframe' is not supported (for information on implementing this, see the support forums)  in /<...>/HTMLDefinition.php on line 311
PHP Stack trace:
<...>
```

Unfortunately, I don't know anything about the Laravel integration here, and how you choose which configuration is active, but if you make sure that the `'youtube'` and `'default'` blocks are actually being combined and used, that should solve your problem.

Comment: I tried to follow your advices and moved all items from  'youtube' under 'default' group and after clearing cach it works ok.
Could you please explain it a bit more detailed and edit in your responce  - and I will accept it...

Comment: You should accept MD Golam Rakib's answer, since that actually solves your problem. :) I'll leave my answer here, as-is, since the information about how I debugged the HTML Purifier side of your problem might be useful to someone who stumbles across this question.